# @Putmapping in SpringBoot delete relationship Object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am using `@Putmapping` to update an object. When I look at the logs it has deleted a relationship. I don't know why, but I need help to understand. My code is below.

I have an object `Employee`, which has a relationship with `Project`. I am updating an `Employee`, but it deletes record from the relationship table.

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}", consumes="application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Employee update(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
    return empService.save(emp);
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_seq", sequenceName = "employee_seq",
    allocationSize = 1,initialValue=1)
    private long employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="project_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Project> projects;

    public Employee() {
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "project_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "project_seq", sequenceName = "project_seq",
    allocationSize = 1,initialValue=1)
    private long projectId;
    private String name;
    private String stage; //NONSTARTED, COMPLETED, INPROGRESS
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST},
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="project_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="employee_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Employee> empList;

    public Project() {

    }
}
```

Comment: In your `update` method, verify that the list of type `Project` is included in the `Employee` body that you're passing in. If it is not, then your code is performing as expected and upating your existing object to remove the relationships.

Comment: You have annotated the projects with @JsonIgnore. On the other hand, you configure it with cascades. I assume, that the incoming Employee object either doesn't have projects or they are not mapped from the json to the entity. Because of the cascade, the relation is removed.